# Can maven treat WEB-INF\lib the way eclipse (and m2e) does?

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-3, m2e, m2e-wtp

I have a servlet/jsp web project which runs fine on eclipse and is exported as war fine ([once I clean it that is](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/72837/1386485/#msg_1386485)). I mavenized the project deleting all of the dependencies from the `WEB-INF\lib` folder *except a homebrew jar* (the output of another project in the workspace). When I run the `package` maven goal I get messages for missing classes from this jar:

```
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
#..... NOTICE THIS COMES FROM A CUSTOM JAR
[ERROR] /C:/path/DataServlet.java:[3,30] package xxx.java.helpers does not exist
```

Now this has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672933/maven-how-to-include-jars-in-eclipse-which-are-not-available-in-repository) and the most rigorous solution appears to be to create a local repo: [Can I add jars to maven 2 build classpath without installing them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364114/can-i-add-jars-to-maven-2-build-classpath-without-installing-them/7623805#7623805) (NB: I am at maven **3**).

I would like to avoid this - so is there any way maven will just stuff this jar to `WEB-INF\lib` *in* the `war` ?

Solutions that use some maven plugin to `cp` the contents of the `WEB-INF\lib` in the war are welcome - although I just have this feeling that there should be a solution that takes into account the "special" nature of this folder.

**Observations:**

- Alt+F5 removes this line:

  ```
  <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.container"/>
  ```

  which corresponds to the "Web App libraries" in the Java Build Path. So not only maven refuses to take into account the `WEB-INF\lib` - it also breaks the build path of eclipse completely.

**Related:**

- [Maven: How to include jars in Eclipse, which are not available in repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672933/maven-how-to-include-jars-in-eclipse-which-are-not-available-in-repository)
- Uses the  maven eclipse plugin : [update my classpath with an Eclipse User Library via the maven eclipse plugin](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-update-my-classpath-with-an-eclipse-user-library-via-the-maven-eclipse-plugin.html) - not compatible with m2e
- [How does the m2e eclipse plugin interact with eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061048/how-does-the-m2e-eclipse-plugin-interact-with-eclipse/13437932#13437932) - apparently m2e checks the pom then calls the eclipse builders (hence the `.classpath` is read)
- [Eclipse maven-enabled web app references workspace projects, but those are not deployed when running Tomcat server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20750774/eclipse-maven-enabled-web-app-references-workspace-projects-but-those-are-not-d)
- [Deploying a Maven project with dependencies to Tomcat or Jboss running within Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564797/deploying-a-maven-project-with-dependencies-to-tomcat-or-jboss-running-within-ec)

Comment: Install a repository manager and install this jar there and that's solved.

Comment: "This question does not show any research effort" - really ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you add this jar from WEB-INF\lib as a dependency like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>someGroupId</groupId>
  <artifactId>someArtifactId</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/homebrew jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I want to avoid the local repo solution - more so the `system` scope that is deprecated - read the links in my answer: "...the most rigorous solution appears to be to create a local repo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364114/can-i-add-jars-to-maven-2-build-classpath-without-installing-them/7623805#7623805"

Comment: They say in that spec that "system" "is considered an advanced kind of feature and should only be used when you truly understand all the ramifications of its use...". If you dont want to have this jar in your WEB-INF/lib folder then probably you need to (as you said) create some own maven repo. Look at Sonatype Nexus (this is some kind of proxy to other repositories which allows you to add own artifacts).